# How can I get the first and last day of the month with Perl's DateTime?

Tags: perl, datetime

Is there a way to figure out the first day of the month (min day) and the last day of a month (max day), given the month as input, using `DateTime` in perl?

So far, I figured out how to pass in a first date, last date to give me a range of days.

But what I want to do now is just pass in a month as an argument, say `201203` and return min, maxday.

Is that possible with DateTime?

Also, I want to change the date format mask from YYYYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD.

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;
    use DateTime;

    unless(@ARGV==2)
    {
        print "Usage: myperlscript first_date last_date\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    my ($first_date,$last_date)=@ARGV;

    my $date=DateTime->new(
    {
      year=>substr($first_date,0,4),
      month=>substr($first_date,4,2),
      day=>substr($first_date,6,2)
    });


while($date->ymd('') le $last_date)
{
  print $date->ymd('') . "\n";
  #$date->add(days=>1); #every day
  $date->add(days=>30);
}
```

Expected Results:

```
2012-03-01
2012-03-31
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[DateTime](https://www.metacpan.org/module/DateTime) does date math for you. You can tell `ymd` which character you want to use as the separator:

```
use DateTime;

my( $year, $month ) = qw( 2012 2 );

my $date = DateTime->new(
    year  =>  $year,
    month => $month,
    day   => 1,
);

my $date2 = $date->clone;

$date2->add( months => 1 )->subtract( days => 1 );

say $date->ymd('-');
say $date2->ymd('-');
```

There are many examples in ["Last day of the month. Any shorter"](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=354580) on Perlmonks, which I found by Googling ["perl datetime last day of month"](http://www.google.com/search?source=ig&hl=en&rlz=&q=perl+datetime+last+day+of+month&btnG=Google+Search).

---

And here's a [Time::Moment](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Time::Moment) example. It's a leaner, faster subset of DateTime:

```
use v5.10;
use Time::Moment;

my( $year, $month ) = qw( 2012 2 );

my $tm = Time::Moment->new(
    year  =>  $year,
    month => $month,
    day   => 1,
);

my $tm2 = $tm->plus_months( 1 )->minus_days( 1 );

say $tm->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
say $tm2->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
```

Answer (score 13):

It is surprising, that neither `DateTime` example uses the special constructor `last_day_of_month` for that (example courtesy of brian d foy):

```
use DateTime;
use strict;
use 5.010;

my( $year, $month ) = qw( 2012 2 );

my $date = DateTime->new(
    year  =>  $year,
    month => $month,
    day   => 1,
);

my $date2 = DateTime->last_day_of_month(  
    year  =>  $date->year,
    month => $date->month,
);

say $date->ymd('-');
say $date2->ymd('-');
```

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative there is the core Perl module `Time::Piece`.

For the current month and year:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -wE '$t=localtime;say $t->month_last_day'
31
```

More generally, something like:

```
use 5.010;
use Time::Piece;
my $MY = shift || die "Month and Year expected\n";
my $t  = Time::Piece->strptime($MY, "%m%Y");
say $t->month_last_day;

$ ./mycode 022012
29
```

Answer (score 6):

First day:

```
$dt->set_day(1);
```

Last day:

```
$dt->set_day(1)->add( months => 1 )->subtract( days => 1 );
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `clone` if you want to avoid changing `$dt`.

Answer (score 2):

While the DateTime class offers a constructor to do this, the most efficient way to get the last day of the month from an existing DateTime object is to request the object to calculate it. <s>The class exposes an undocumented method _month_length() that calculates the last day of the month very efficiently. With your DateTime object called $date, you can try</s>

```
$date->_month_length($date->year,$date->month);
```

This method is undocumented, so it may or may not be supported in your version of DateTime. Use with caution.

**UPDATE**

As a result of my [request](https://github.com/houseabsolute/DateTime.pm/issues/60), starting from v1.144 DateTime added official support for [month_length](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#$dt-%3Emonth_length()). When using this later version, you can use

```
$date->month_length($date->year,$date->month);
```

Comment: The Perl methods that start with an underscore are typically private methods (since Perl doesn't have those). They are undocumented because you aren't supposed to use them. They may change or disappear since they aren't part of the public interface.

Comment: @briandfoy, you are 100% correct! Notice that I mention in the answer the same advice that you helpfully provided in your comment. This answer, plus advocacy in the github issues, was useful to get the `DateTime` project to add this functionality to the public interface. Yay!

Comment: Hey, very cool that you got the feature you wanted in the module!